# MySQL select records, count duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have a table of posts, each post has an IP address, I want to see how many times that IP has posted by counting how many times it occurs in the database, and then putting the number of times it's appeared on the screen. Basically this:

MySQL Table:

```
id entry     ip
1   abc  19.123.14.5
2   cde  19.123.14.5
3   efg  12.231.22.9
```

I want the code to take that, count duplicates, and ouput the count like so:

```
id entry     ip       count
1   abc  19.123.14.5    2
2   efg  12.231.22.9    1
```

Here's my code (that doesn't work) so far:

```
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT ip, entry, id, COUNT(ip) AS A FROM table_name AS C GROUP BY ip HAVING COUNT A > 1 ORDER BY id DESC");
    $i = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $entry = $row['entry'];
        $ip = $row['ip'];
        $count = ?????;
        $i++;
    ?>

    <tr width="100%" align="center">
        <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $entry; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $ip; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $count ?></td>
        <td>
        <form style="display:inline;" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $ip; ?>" name="ip" />
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" name="id" />
            <input type="submit" value="Ban IP" name="submit" />
        </form>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <?php
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT:
Doesn't work: Well firstly, as obvious from my code, the variable $count has nothing assigned to it as I have no idea what to put there. Secondly, I get this error:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource
```

Comment: Have done, see edit at the bottom.

Comment: `$count = $row['A'];` should work in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ip, min(entry), max(id) as id, COUNT(ip) AS A 
FROM table_name AS C 
GROUP BY ip
ORDER BY max(id) DESC
```

You were missing to do MAX(id) since you want to group by IP and entry. You can drop the `Having>1` since you want to see counts =1 according to your sample output

Sample script:

```
declare @table table
(
id int,
entry varchar(20),
ip varchar(20)
)
    insert into @table
    values

(1,   'abc',  '19.123.14.5'),
(2,   'cde' , '19.123.14.5'),
(3 ,  'efg',  '12.231.22.9')


SELECT  max(id) as id, ip, max(entry), COUNT(ip) AS count 
FROM @table AS C 
GROUP BY ip
ORDER BY max(id) asc
```

Produces:

```
id          ip                                        count
----------- -------------------- -------------------- -----------
2           19.123.14.5          cde                  2
3           12.231.22.9          efg                  1
```

Comment: `min(entry)` and `max(id)` could come from two different rows in the table. I don't think that would be desirable in the output. I would think that those two values should correspond to the same row.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli good point but if that's the case his sample output is wrong. Look at column with id=2. Comes from a different record. I don't think it really matters to OP but that's for him to clarify.

Comment: It doesn't matter to me, I just need to count the IP duplicates. At the moment (with this code and the code below) it returns an empty row in the table that it creates.

Comment: @Icarus The sample output must be wrong as that ip address (12.231.22.9) belongs to id 3, not id 2.

Comment: @AviateX14 I just posted a sample script (on SQL Server) but MySQL should return the same. If that's not the case something is really odd with MySQL.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli precisely, I take it that OP only cares about counting duplicate IP addresses.

Comment: That all seems like what I want, however, when I run the code it returns a blank row (in the table I create on the page)

Comment: @AviateX14 Take the query and run it on MySQL directly. It should produce rows. You seem to have more issues than just the query being wrong judging by the other warning you get from `mysql_fetch_array()`

Comment: You're right, it does produce rows, so the issue is with the way the data is presented. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have different `id`s and `entries` for `ip=19.123.14.5`. Which one of them you wish to choose?

For just counting `ip`s and ignoring `id` and `entry` altogether:

```
SELECT ip, COUNT(*)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY ip

12.231.22.9, 1
19.123.14.5, 2
```

For selecting a random row out of many that might be connected to the same `ip` (this is MySQL specific and would not work under other databases):

```
SELECT id, entry, ip, COUNT(*)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY ip

3, efg, 12.231.22.9, 1
1, abc, 19.123.14.5, 2 // Might also be: 2, cde, 19.123.14.5, 2
```

For selecting all rows, together with `ip` counts:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name t2 WHERE t1.ip = t2.ip)
FROM
    table_name t1

1, abc, 19.123.14.5, 2
2, cde, 19.123.14.5, 2
3, efg, 12.231.22.9, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.id, t.entry, t.ip, q.IpCount 
    FROM (SELECT ip, MIN(id) AS MinId, COUNT(*) AS IpCount
              FROM table_name
              GROUP BY ip) q
        INNER JOIN table_name t
            ON q.ip = t.ip
                AND q.MinId = t.id
    ORDER BY t.id DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your result/example table that you want to build has something that is not that rational. You cannot combine ID and ENTRY with counter of IPs. For example, the first row in your result / example table says that IP `19.123.14.5` has been found 2 times, which is correct, but associates it to ID `1` and ENTRY `abc`. Why? What is the reason you do not associate it to ID `2` and ENTRY `cde`. There is also another mistake (? ... I cannot tell ...) on the row with ID `2` and ENTRY `efg`. This combination does not exist in the initial table that you give. The resulting table with all 4 columns says nothing.

Unless you want to display always the first (minimum) ID, ENTRY that the particular IP was found. Is that so?

**If this is so** then your SQL is not correct. The correct SQL is:

```
 select aa.min_id as id, 
           b.entry, 
           aa.ip as ip, 
           aa.count_ip as count     
 from table_name b     
 join (select min(a.id) as min_id, 
                 a.ip, 
                 count(a.ip) as count_ip 
          from table_name a 
          group by a.ip) aa 
      on aa.min_id = b.id;
```

Comment: Looks a lot like [the answer I posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894573/mysql-select-records-count-duplicates/7894684#7894684) 28 minutes earlier.

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli Sorry, but I was doing the solution off-line. Then I posted. BTW, your solution has a join `q.ip=t.ip` which is not necessary. But, yes, otherwise, they are the same.

Comment: It's probably overkill, but I included the `ip` in the join because I did not want to make any assumptions about `id` being unique.

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli Yes, you are right that you didn't make any assumption. But now this is irrelavant :-) since the person who asked picked up as an answer the wrong answer according to my rational. Hence, so long...